# Why is 'MatrixOrderPrepend' the default transformation order in GDI+?

Tags: gdi+

I recently had to modify an MFC app to do some pretty graphics (simulate an LCD display). This is not my home turf but I managed to solve it with GDI+; GraphicsPath, bezier curves and matrix transformations are now my friends. But what struck me as odd is that the matrix transformation operations seem backwards by default.

If I do something like...

```
Graphics g;
g.TranslateTransform( ... )
g.RotateTransform( ...)
s.ScaleTransform( ... )
```

...then the transformations are applied the opposite order: scale, then rotate, then translate. This is counterintuitive to me.

I know that I can add a parameter to the transform calls to change the behaviour to what I want, like this:

```
g.RotateTransform( ..., MatrixOrderAppend)
g.ScaleTransform( ..., MatrixOrderAppend)
```

What is the rationale for having `MatrixOrderPrepend` as default?

Answer (score 1):

On MSDN is a short article [Why Transformation Order Is Significant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
I'm not sure why 'MatrixOrderPrepend' is the default value, but obviously either have very valid applications. Guess they had to pick one, wouldn't worry to much about !